# Received error "Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3001/favicon.ico'" when loading another html by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am making a MERN-stack web with html/css/javascript(React, Node.js), and now is trying to make the log in function. 
The authentication things work fine, but when javascript loading another html file, I received the error which said can not found the favorite.ico file.

Here is the code from App.js:

```
getDataFromDb = (userName, password) => {
  let validOrNot = false;
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getData')
    .then((data) =>
      data.json()
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        data: res.data
      })
      this.state.data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.userName === userName && item.password === password) {
          console.log('item.username: ' + item.userName + ', username:' + userName)
          console.log('item.pass:' + item.password + ', pass: ' + password)
          validOrNot = true
        }
      })

      this.setState({
        goToMainPage: validOrNot
      })
      console.log(this.state.goToMainPage)
      if (this.state.goToMainPage) {
        this.setState({
          goToMainPage: false
        })
        console.log('LogIn function running, now goToMainPage has been false');
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001/i.html'
      }
    })
};
```

Here is part of i.html which should be loaded:

```
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

And here is the error message:

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3001/favicon.ico' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Comment: bro, what happened? did you find a solution?